# Клонирование DIV с присвоением нового ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html

Всем привет! Есть DIV, при его перетаскивании он остается на месте, но создается его копия. Копия перетаскивается на другой DIV. Так можно перетаскивать сколько угодно раз (всегда создается копия первого DIV). Так вот, обязательно, чтобы при создании-перетаскивании-сбрасывании у каждого нового элемента появлялся новый ID. 
Помогите плз с этой задачей)

З.Ы.: Я сделал перетаскивание, но новый  ID существует лишь до сбрасывания на другой DIV (т.е. во время таскания). Добавляется div уже без ID.

Comment: Вы про это?

    $(cloneDiv).setAttr('id', 'newId')

Comment: ну да. только вот существует новый id только во время таскания. а, когда сбрасываю-добавляется блок без ID :(

Comment: Ну вот, посмотрите евент онДроп...

Comment: Да, что я только не пробовал. Мне бы конкретнее) Вот, например, у меня в `draggable` есть параметр `connectToSortable`. Может с ним что-то не так?

Comment: Выложите пожалуйста код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это ведь jquery ui? Я угадал? Если да и вы используете draggable и sortable то:

У sortable есть [event recive](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-receive) где в аргументе **ui.item** находится свежеиспеченый jquery object который создался после "сбрасывания", ну а далее как сказал [@shurik](/users/1182/shurik)

```
ui.item.setAttr('id', 'newId')
```